# Ubuntu 17.10 doesn't see my wi-fi network after reboot

Tags: wireless, network-manager

My ubuntu doesn't see my wi-fi network after reboot... The most interesting is that it sees some another networks but not my router or Android phone. I can't get even what can be a reason... In Windows on same laptop all works.
Where can problem be? I haven't ideas just. I tried to restart NetworkManager service, it doesn't help.
`lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Askey Computer Corp. BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [144f:7179]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
Kernel modules: bcma
06:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [11ab:4354]
Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller [144d:c07f]
Kernel driver in use: sky2
Kernel modules: sky2
3f:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 02)
```

**P.S.** I need to finish my project today, so Wi-Fi is very important for me now I haven't any yet connection for my laptop.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`  And do you know what channel your router is using?

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have added `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: My router uses 12th channel.

Comment: I suspect it might work if your router was on 1 - 11

Comment: I have switched my channel to 6th... But it became to work after driver re-installation only

Answer (score 0):

It helped me to re-install the Broadcom driver by [this article](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/broadcom).
Basic steps:

- Remove an existing package:
  `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`
- Update cache:
  `sudo apt-get update`
- Update PCI.ID lists: 
  `sudo update-pciids`
- Install b43-installer:
  `sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`
- Reboot your system

**ADDED**
I have switched a Wi-Fi channel on my router to 6th from 12th.